# Liquid layouts and borders

Tags: html, css, forms, liquid-layout

I am having problems with a liquid layout and borders, causing elements to overflow.

- Here is a jfiddle with the exmaple of
  the page with no borders (works
  fine): http://jsfiddle.net/eRaB5/1/
- Now here is an example of what I want
  to happen, but it breaks.
  http://jsfiddle.net/eRaB5/2/

The structure is somewhat like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <label>Label</label><input type="text' />
</div>

#container{width: 100%;}
label{width: 25%;}
input{width: 75;}
```

I need the values to add up to 100% so the left and right edges align. Only the borders on the input make the input widths effectively `width: 100% +2px;`

Is there any way around this problem using just CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Negative margins

You can try by setting negative margins:

```
margin: -1px;
```

I've changed them on your jsFiddle and textboxes did jump right of label.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/eRaB5/3/

Just add

```
margin: -1px;
```

to `.input-text` class.